# Linksys gateway unable to set static IP of my PC

Tags: gateway

I got a Linksys gateway WAG54G2 and there is a problem, that I can't find in the gateway web-configuration how to set static IP for my PC using cable connection. Firmware Version:V1.00.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Linksys firmwares do not allow you to set static IPs from the router. You can only do it on the PC itself with manual networking settings.

Most Windows PCs can use Control Panel to get to network settings (example: "Network and Dialup Connections" then "Local Area Connection" then "Properties"). Navigate to the settings for "TCP/IP" (example: "Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)").

Change from "Obtain an IP address automatically" to "Use the following IP address". Enter these values (all are important and exact wording may vary):

- IP address: 192.168.1.# (find out from router subnet mask)
- Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
- Default Gateway: 192.168.1.1
- DNS servers: (find out from router)

[image]

Comment: I tried this, and it works. For one time. After restart it ALWAYS doesn't work at all. I tried setting DNS to gataway IP, to proper IP, and no IP, all of that is working only till I restart my computer :(